# How to add object coordinates to instance coordinates?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, coordinates

I'm trying to create infinite "Teleport Waves"
[image]

and everything is going well until I try to move the teleport itself. Then the waves stay in place.
[image]

My attempts to intercept the coordinates of the object itself and add them to the coordinates of the instances were unsuccessful. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image] (Blender v 4.0.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set coordinates to original:

[image]

*Relative* means torus will change position than you move object because coordinates are relative to current object, not to world center.